# Removing old folders and keeping the most recent

Tags: powershell, directory

I have been working on a script of late and have come across a snag. I am in the process of removing folders which are automatically created. I want to delete the older versions of those files whilst keeping the new folders untouched, for example:

- 18.212.1021.0008   //Created on the 19/11/2018 12:12
- 18.212.1021.0008_1 //Created on the 19/11/2018 12:23
- 18.212.1021.0008_2 //Created on the 19/11/2018 12:27
- 18.212.1021.0008_3 //Created on the 19/11/2018 12:32

I would want to keep 18.212.1021.008_3 so I guess I would need to keep the folder with the most recent creation date.

Please see the code below:

```
    $Versionarray = 13..20
    Get-ChildItem "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive" -Recurse | Where-Object {
        # Recusivly deletes OneDrive version folders within
        # Appdata\local which build up everytime OneDrive
        # is installed/script is run
        $item = $_
        $item -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] -and (
            $Versionarray | Where-Object { $item.Name.Contains($_) }
        )
    } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: The sample code you posted is broken. Please create a [mcve], then [edit] your question and post *that* code along with all errors *that* code throws. Also, do the names all folders you want processed have the same format? Like, some text optionally followed by an underscore and a number?

Comment: Apologies, I have removed the curly bracket below it. This should now work. If the folder is locked by the system you might see a few errors but this would be the folder I would want to avoid and keep.

Comment: Please also answer the question from my previous comment.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Your question is an interesting on. Sooo, the folder is randomly  generated. The folder relates to the version so if the folder name for the original version is free then OneDrive will use that. If it's not then it will add an underscore and increment the number. 

This means that if you have 18.212.1021.0008, 18.212.1021.0008_1, 18.212.1021.0008_2 and delete "18.212.1021.0008" then the next time OneDrive re-creates the folder it will use 18.212.1021.0008. Hence why I want the others removed to stop the folder getting bunged up with lots of folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the newest folder you want to keep is also the one with the newest creation time, you can use this simple one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive" -Directory | sort CreationTime | select -SkipLast 1 | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

If you want to filter out only a specific type of folders by name, you could use a simple regex match. I cannot help you with the exact regex (since I would have to know your folder naming pattern) but it would look something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\OneDrive" -Directory | where Name -match '\d\d+' | sort CreationTime | select -SkipLast 1 | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

(Note that this is syntax might not work if you use an old Powershell version. If that's the case, let me know and I will provide a compatible fallback solution.)

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment: Your requirements are still a bit unclear, but here is something to get you started:

If you want to make sure to only delete folders that "look like" version folders, you can adjust the regex in the where-filter. `_\d+$` will match anything with an underscore and numbers at the end:

```
where $_.Name -match '_\d+$'
```

If you also want to make sure, that this is actually a versioned copy of another existing folder, you could check that too:

```
where { $_.FullName -match '^(?<OriginalPath>.+)_\d+$' -and (Test-Path $Matches.OriginalPath) }
```

Comment: That looks great, the only issue is there are other folders in there like:

- OneDrive.exe
- Logs
- Help

This is why I have an array for looking for folders with numbers in them. :)

Comment: Marsze, that is one sexy one-liner. I love it.

Comment: Hi Marsze, looking at my response to AnsgarWiechers is there anyway to target only those version folders? If I run my full script over and over eventually it breaks down, it could be removing other folders.

Comment: @Marshal I've extended my answer. I hope that helps you to get started and create your final solution yourself.